# Binding to something other than ToString: how?

Tags: xaml, binding, methods

I wasn't very happy with the default `ToString()` output from the [PhysicalAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.aspx) class in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace. The output is formatted like "AABBCCDDEEFF",
so I wrote an extension method `ToDelimitedString()` that returns it formatted like "AA-BB-CC-DD-FF".

So far, so good. Now I want to display this in my WPF application through the use of databinding, but this is where the road stops for me. I don't really know how to bind to anything other than the default `ToString()` on object instances.

Someone please point me in the right direction, I'm having terrible difficulty in understanding the msdn documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way is probably to write a converter:

```
public class PhysicalAdressConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var address = value as PhysicalAddress;
        if (address != null)
            return address.ToDelimitedString();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And specify this converter in your binding to the `PhysicalAddress`

If you're using the MVVM pattern, you can also create a property that performs the formatting and bind to this property:

```
public string FormattedPhysicalAddress
{
    get { return this.PhysicalAddress.ToDelimitedString(); }
}
```

BTW, a binding doesn't bind to the `ToString()` method as you seem to assume. It binds to the value itself, but if the target type is `string`, *then* it calls `ToString()` to make it a string...

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for clearing up the confusion too. Let me try this.

Comment: I took the IValueConverter approach (although I do try to use MVVM) and it works beatifully. :)

Can I ask though where it would be appropriate to implement ConvertBack? I can't think of any use cases. If you ever needed the original value, you would just get it directly from the source, right?

Comment: @StevenDotNet, ConvertBack is used only for two-way binding. It converts the value from the control back to the DataContext property

Comment: Ah! Everything makes sense now. Thanks.